# CMake older version error, i tried many commands from online sites but still older version error exists, anyone knows reason?

Tags: linux, build, yocto, bitbake

I have already installed newer version of CMake still when I use bitbake command I get error that I have older version. How to overcome this??

$ cmake --version

cmake version 3.22.1

**But still this shows up during bitbake:**

Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate

| DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished

| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure

| CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):

|   **CMake 3.10 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.8.2**

Comment: What yocto branch are you using? Also, what bitbake command you are running?

Comment: I created a layer and have recipe in it and i used bitbake to run my recipe. Yocto branch i dont know.

Comment: Is your code source online? I think it is demanding a cmake version higher than your Yocto cmake recipe version and not your HOST cmake, `cd` into `poky` and run `git branch`.